# console.log showing data but getting error in if condition javascript (using inside react component)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to Javascript, I am trying to invoke code on onClick event inside React container component below is my code

```
  const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    if (e != null){
      const row_id = e.target.getAttribute('key');
      var cur_row;
      if (api_data != undefined || api_data != null){
      for (cur_row=0; api_data.length-1; cur_row++){
        console.log('this is api data', api_data[cur_row]['id'])
        if (api_data[cur_row]['id'] == row_id){
          console.log(api_data[cur_row])
          break
        }
      }}
  }}
```

in above code api_data is hookstate variable in which i am storing data. in console log I am able to see the data but when it comes to if condition which is right below the console.log statement I am getting error 'Cannot read property 'id' of undefined'. I searched some similar questions but not able to understand who to fix my problem. Any idea what I am missing

Comment: is for loop correct?
I guess it should be:  for(cur_row=0; curr_row < = api_data.length-1; cur_row++){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const onClickHandler = (e) => {
    if (e != null){
      const row_id = e.target.getAttribute('key');
      var cur_row;
      if (api_data != undefined || api_data != null){
/* 
I guess you forgot to add exit statement in for loop, 
because of it curr_row value was increasing way beyond 
api_data.length giving you undefined output and hence that error
*/
      for (cur_row=0; curr_row <= api_data.length-1; cur_row++){
        console.log('this is api data', api_data[cur_row]['id'])
        if (api_data[cur_row]['id'] == row_id){
          console.log(api_data[cur_row])
          break
        }
      }}
  }}
```